# If a process is running, then dont do anything

Tags: bash, ansible

I am a beginner with Ansible, and I would like to modify an existing yml, to check if a script is running, before running all the tasks.

The tasks are executed in different machines, here an example:

```
- hosts: server1
  become: True
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: task1
      shell: command

    - name: task2
      shell: command2
```

And my bash command to detect if a script is running, is this one:

```
if ps -aux 2>/dev/null| grep string_to_search | grep name_of_the_script > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "script_running"; else "script_not_running"; fi
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
If script running --> Then dont run the following tasks, just exit.
If not running --> Then proceed with the following tasks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your command should just check the non existence of your script as a process (since if it exists it does nothing).
So just check if the result of your `ps | grep` operations is null with `-z` flag:

```
if [[ -z $(ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep "name_of_the_script") ]]; then do_something; fi
```

NB: Before searching the script name, pipe the output of the `ps` command to `grep -v "grep"` to exclude your current grep process from the `ps` result. Otherwise the test will always be evaluated to false.

Comment: But the thing is, that that command must run as the first task, and if that task succeed, the rest wont execute.